# How to validate jwt token from different issuer

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, azure-logic-apps, adaptive-cards

I'm using actionable messages (with Outlook web app) to call an Logic App. Therefore I am getting an Bearer token in the request:

"Action-Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAi..."

Callstack:
`Outlook web app -> Logic App -> my endpoint hosted in azure`

Now I tried to validate the token with jwt.io but getting an Issue that the Signature is invalid. 
So I tried to validate it in c# with the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

I tried to add `https://substrate.office.com/sts/` to the issuer list, but it seems like the validation don't even get there.

I'm using the following code to validate the jwt token issued by office.com:

```cs
bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var valid = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);

            // Custom handle for Bearer token, when invalid from base-class
            if (!valid && actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme == "Bearer")
            {
                var jwt = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                var th = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var sjwt = th.ReadToken(jwt) as JwtSecurityToken;                

                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    //IssuerSigningToken = sjwt,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { "https://substrate.office.com/sts/" },
                    ValidAudiences = new[] {"https://XXX.logic.azure.com"}
        };

                SecurityToken validatedToken;
                try
                {
                    th.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return valid;
        }
```

Here is my JWT token:

[image: JWT Token]

I am getting the exception:

```
IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 2,
    Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x818...),
    Clause[1] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
', ...
```

Even though I set `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false`.

Is there a way to accept `https://substrate.office.com/sts/` as a valid issuer?

Comment: Could you show us what does your token look like ? the issuer should be the value in the "iss" claim

Comment: Also the `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` has a different purpose. It is here to validate that the token has been issued by the `right\wanted` authorization server. You should not set this property to false

Comment: I added the token. ```ValidateIssuerSigningKey=false``` is only for testing purpose, i thought this would mitigate the exception I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that the "Signature validation failed".
To resolve this problem we can't just add the wanted valid issuer to `ValidIssuers`, we need the to verify that the token is issued from the issuer itself.

Especially for this case with office.com being the issuer I found the expected key (JWK - JSON Web Key) here:
https://substrate.office.com/sts/common/discovery/keys
(also https://substrate.office.com/sts/common/.well-known/openid-configuration)

Here is the working code:

```
bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var valid = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);

            // Custom handle for Bearer token, when invalid from base-class
            if (!valid && actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme == "Bearer")
            {
                var jwt = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                var th = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new JsonWebKey(GetJWK()),
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { "https://substrate.office.com/sts/" }
                };

                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken validatedToken;
                try
                {
                    var claims = th.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
                    valid = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }

            return valid;
        }

        // Get the token from configuration
        private string GetJWK()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:jwks_json"];
        }
```

In the appsettings I put the RSA key from the website for validating the token, it looks like:

```
{"kty":"RSA","use":"sig","kid":"gY...","x5t":"gY...","n":"2w...","e":"AQAB","x5c":["MII..."]}
```

Comment: Just a tip: You're using a lot of manual steps that can be prevented by using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token in combination with using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols Nugets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an OAuth spec JWT then the key to validate the ticket can be retrieved via 'http://auth.myApplication.com/.well-known/jwks.json' and the built in JwtSecurityTokenHandler can be used even if you're using the older System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt which does not have the calls natively built in.

OWIN Example:

```
public static class AppBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use JWT Authentication.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> to use.</param>
    /// <param name="audiences">The expected audiences.  Will be validated in the token.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> instance.</returns>
    public static IAppBuilder UseJwtTokenAuthentication(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        params string[] audiences)
    {
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                   {
                                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                                       ValidateAudience = true,
                                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                                       ValidateActor = true,
                                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                       ValidAudiences = audiences,
                                       ValidIssuer = Constants.Issuer,
                                       IssuerSigningKeyResolver = Constants.GetSigningKey,
                                   };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = audiences,
                TokenHandler = tokenHandler,
                TokenValidationParameters = validationParameters,
            });

        return app;
    }
}

public static class Constants
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The authentication issuer.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Issuer = "https://auth.myApplication.com/"; // custom domain for Auth0

    private static readonly OpenIdConnectKeyResolver KeyResolver;

    static Constants() { KeyResolver = new OpenIdConnectKeyResolver(Issuer, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="IssuerSigningKeyResolver" /> delegate to provide to <see cref="JwtSecurityTokenHandler" />.
    /// </summary>
    public static IssuerSigningKeyResolver GetSigningKey => KeyResolver.GetSigningKey;
}
```

Direct call Example:

```
        void ValidateToken(string authenticationToken)
        {
            var issuer = "https://auth.myApplication.com/"; // custom domain for Auth0
            var audiences = new[]
                            {
                                "https://secure.myApplication.com/",
                            };

            using (var signingKeyResolver = new OpenIdConnectKeyResolver(issuer, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                           {
                                               ValidateLifetime = true,
                                               ValidateAudience = true,
                                               ValidateIssuer = true,
                                               ValidateActor = true,
                                               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                               ValidAudiences = audiences,
                                               ValidIssuer = issuer,
                                               IssuerSigningKeyResolver = signingKeyResolver.GetSigningKey,
                                           };

                var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authenticationToken, validationParameters, out var securityToken);

                if (principal == null || securityToken == null)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
                }
            }
        }
```

This requires a signing key resolver, the example is using the second option as that's what I needed:

It is baked into Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (see example here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin/blob/master/src/Auth0.Owin.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver/OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver.cs).

It is a little more work if using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (see example here: https://github.com/NaosProject/Naos.Auth/blob/main/Naos.Auth.Recipes.Jwt/OpenIdConnectKeyResolver.cs) I wrote a piece of code to accomplish this which can be copied directly (MIT license) or installed as a mix-in using package 'Naos.Auth.Recipes.Jwt'.